# update values in the Reducer in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-router

i got two values i.e.**company and id** from navigation.

```
let id = props.route.params.oved;
console.log("id-->",id);
let company = props.route.params.company;
console.log("company--->",company);
```

i got two values as a integer like this:--

```
id-->1
comapny-->465
```

[image]

Description of the image:---

if i am giving input 1 in that textInput and click on the card(lets say first card i.e.465 then i am getting those two values in navigation as in interger that i have mention above.so each time i am getting updated values.

i am getting updated values from navigation.

so i want to store those values in redux.

action.js:--

```
import { CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY } from "./action-constants";
export const changeCompany = (updatedCompany, updatedId) => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY,
    updatedCompany,
    updatedId,
  };
};
```

reducer.js:--

```
import { CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY } from "../actions/action-constants";

const initialState = {
  company: "",
  id: "",
};
const changeCompanyReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SELECTED_COMPANY:
      return {
        company: {
          company: action.updatedCompany,
          id: action.updatedId,
        },
      };
    
  }
  return state;
};

export default changeCompanyReducer;
```

congigure-store.js:--

```
import changeCompanyReducer from "./reducers/change-company-reducer";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({changeCompanyReducer});
```

How can i store the update values getting from navigation in Redux?

could you please write code for redux??

Answer (score 0):

in the component create a function that updates the values

```
const updateReducer = () => {
  dispatch(changeCompany(props.route.params.oved, props.route.params.company))
}
```

then call the function in react navigation lifecycle event

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      updateReducer()
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation])
```

its possible that a better solution would be to update the reducer before the navigation happens and not pass the data in the params but rather pull it from redux but this is the answer to the question as asked